# Use CMAES optimizer in Elastix, How to define class TElastix?

Tags: itk, image-registration, elastix-itk

I'm trying to write my own registration method by using iTk and elastix, I do have some experience in iTk but I just started to use its extension called Elastix.

I want to use CMAES optimizer in elastix to find the optimized values of translation and rotation for rigid registration but I don't know how to use CMAES in elastix, it needs a class template called TElastix and I don't know what is this and how should I define it, so does anyone have experience in elastix? or can someone give me some example codes to see how to use elastix source codes?

Thanks in advance